# c# insert multiple rows of listview into SQL check all items for errors before inserting

Tags: c#, sql

I have a listview on a C# windows form application. I want to insert all of its items into a SQL table. I can do this by iterating through all items and insert them one by one. but I need to make sure that all items will be inserted without any errors. if there is even one error in all items the application raise that error and don't insert any items at all.
How can I do this?

Comment: You need to make sure the models you're inserting are validated against your DB tables constraints. Since you're using WinForms I don't believe there is much in terms of validation helpers, so you're going to have to build methods to validate your models before persisting them to the DB.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a [transaction](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/controlling-transactions.php).

Comment: validating data through form can be a good practice but does not assure data integrity completely. I agree with your second command, TRANSACTION.

Answer (score 1):

@AmoExcel

Hello,

You are going to want to use a transaction that wraps the totality of all your inserts over the same connection. I'll skip talking about bulk inserts etc atm but assuming you have a singular way to loop through and put all the records in.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   try
   {
      connection.Open();

      using (SqlTransaction mysingleTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
      {
         // just a pseudo example not real code in this part of the loop
         foreach (line in the grid)
         {

            // in here I would put my code that loops through my rows of data
            // then creates a sqlcommand using the existing transaction
            // it will rollback if it fails and drops into the Exception path

             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", connection, mysingleTransaction))
             {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                foreach (var commandString in sqlCommandList)
                {
                   command.CommandText = commandString;
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
             }
          }

          // once you did all your inserts, commit it

          mysingleTransaction.Commit();
       }        
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //error occurred
    {
       // Do what you want with the error and everything rolls back
    }
```

}